# How to resolve "Type circularly references itself error"?

Tags: typescript, circular-reference

What follows is an example of issue with an expected outcome:

```js
const actionTypes = {
  name: {
    set: "name/set",
  },
} as const;

type ActionTypes = { [key: string]: (string | ActionTypes) }; //record value is string or ActionTypes

// "GetActionType" circularly references itself
type GetActionType<A extends ActionTypes> = A extends Record<
  string,
  infer Value
>
  ? Value extends string
    ? Value
    : GetActionType<Value> // "GetActionType" is not generic
  : unknown;

type SiteAction = GetActionType<typeof actionTypes>; // "GetActionType" is not generic
// expected to be 'name/set'
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without running into an error?

### Edit

Adds `as const` to declaration of actionTypes nad references the constant correctly below

TypeScript version `4.0.2`

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhsKBLcAVAngBwKYRgXhgG8AoGGMOAW2wC5izyYJsp6AiSmgehanYA0jAL5Dh8PKEhQA3CRJQs2GAEFEKMBhx5CRGAG0A1tnT1oAJyRgA5gF16ACgtXrMAD6r1aJRACUMYRkYbm5zbFBzABMYADc4ABsAV2UkPGcbGBBzT2RvbXkQmHYAcVY1XM0ldhhgJHNgRPi4c3j0GDCAM2wwsGBcGCQoFniOhSUYUqhyjS1sAB4VGGwADyhsMEi8abzcAD4CVSXV9c2YACVwrMi5xnTrIXIrLuyANQTkkl3GAH4YN6TlCs1hs0lBLDZGORfv8PkwYPRJttKjg5jDsPtCiUyl5kdhqqkKCBYNZ1t0kMBGPREmBDGAQAB3MByMY4GAAZUG2CRB0RONmc0UOBAHXgfJ8uyCmN5FVm+LwdOJpMsFMKKxwiGw0SgIBgACNlAByLjYXisA1AA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

Two main diff from your approach:

- flipped `Value extends string` to `Value extends ActionTypes` for recursion
- marked `siteActionTypes` to `as const` to infer specific types

```js
const siteActionTypes = {
  name: {
    set: 'name/set'
  }
} as const

type ActionTypes = { [key: string]: string | ActionTypes }

type GetActionType<A extends ActionTypes> = A extends Record<string, infer Value>
  ? Value extends ActionTypes
    ? GetActionType<Value>
    : Value
  : unknown

type SiteAction = GetActionType<typeof siteActionTypes>
// SiteAction has type 'name/set'
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200914#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCWUCmBBYV7gCoE8AOSEMAvDAN4CwAUDDGAIYC2SAXOdbbRElGwOQNmAem5Q+HGAF9qkmPSKhIUatSj4kMNBmzqipMjADaAayQ420AE7wwAcwC6FqNbswAPpvSYwuAkWlUquowAOI8Wt6+SAA8KDBIAB7IYAAmRBE6fgB8JJrxSUipRABKSKCWKdFWNrYANDA2AGZIljAAavQANgCuSFkSAPztXb35yWme2j66ErRDYVAZ0wTRHT19szBsa70SbN1gxmAgAO5gKlRqBDAAyoioXuC5C0tR0VdIII1w96+6-VQhEJbr9HmAYAALeQwD4wARMJAiHh8IA)

Comment: Still have the same errors can you post a repl link?

Comment: Added in the answer, this could be the version issue. This works on typescript nightly build. They seem to have fixed something in nightly

Comment: The link points to an incomplete example, but you're right!

Comment: Thanks, I've complicated the [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200914#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhsKBLcAVAngBwKYRgXhgG8AoGGMOAW2wC5izyYJsp6AiSmgehanYA0jAL5DyceqSYwARvQDkceWKbBJjaQBMF2ZRpjCRJYfDyhIUANwkSULNhgBBRCjAYceQkRgBtANbY6PTQAE5IYADmALr0ABSh4REwAD5OLmj2EACUBtYk3Nww7ADirM7IGTjsMMBIIcAArgA2cCFN6DAh2ABm2F1gwLgwSFAsTd229jClUOWu7tgAPI4w2AAeUNhgmnhzlbgAfAROqxtbOzAAStigIZqLjAmRKuG9ITAAanBNDdgkB4wAPyfb6-U6bba7dJuTL6YEzPYwnCLL4-bAA6T0VG-Rj0BpgPxgEAAdzAeTsOBgAGURthEccEdCFosKdgQN14EzMgdrAUKNRsLxWCkYIp5CL5LoSEA) slightly to see if the solution holds and it does.